# How to include the 'id' (field) of an entity in the response after a POST (create) event in Apigility?

Tags: rest, laminas-api-tools

Given a `json` string:

```
POST localhost:8080/person  
{
   f_name : 'Juan',  
   l_name : 'Dela Cruz'  
}
```

we would usually return a **boolean** `true` value upon **success** so that apigility would return/render something like this:

```
200 Ok  
{  
    f_name : 'Juan',  
    l_name : 'Dela Cruz'  
}
```

How can I also include the `id` of the newly created entity in the resulting response? It may look something like this:

```
200 Ok  
{  
    id : 1,
    f_name : 'Juan',  
    l_name : 'Dela Cruz'  
}
```

Any help/lead is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am including my own answer here, but I think this is not the best possible way.

I have discovered that you can also return an `array` from the create (`POST`) method of the resource with the 'id' field taken from the `lastInsertValue` property of an db `adapter` object and added into the `array`.

```
$insert['f_name'] = 'Juan';  
$insert['l_name'] = 'Dela Cruz';

$table = new TableGateway('person', $adapter);
$table->insert($insert);

$insert['id'] = $table->lastInsertValue;

return $insert;
```

I hope there are still other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Apigility does indeed return the object you send. If you want to get a different result you can construct it yourself and return it as 
javiniar.leonard also pointed out.

Important is that you do not try to json_encode it but let Apigility handle that.

I use the API to send items created in an app with a local id, and return the local id and web_id to allow for synchronization on multiple devices.